# sir/maam i really need your help in this one i tried to change the platform into x64 but it's effective

Tags: vb.net

sir/maam im just really desperate in here im sorry i really need your help in this one i tried to change the platform into x64 but it's effective i dont know how to solve this i hope you can give me any suggestion im begging.

ERROR: File 'log4net.dll' targeting 'AMD64' is not compatible with the project's target platform 'x86'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdr9b.png)

Comment: The fact that you have no badges indicates that you rejected the prompt to take the site tour when you registered. That was a mistake. Please take that tour and spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to properly write a question on SO. It requires ALL the facts and ONLY the facts, so "please", "thank you", "sorry" and the like have no place. Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and a title that summarises the issue and nothing more. If someone answers, you thank them by accepting or up-voting their answer if it's a solution or otherwise helpful.

Comment: thank you for the tip and suggestions sir/ma'am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that your project is referencing a specifically 64-bit version of the log4net library. Remove the reference and add back a reference to a version that supports 32-bit applications.